# Is the class of polynomial rings an axiomatizable class?

Tags: ring-theory, model-theory

I define a polynomial ring to be a ring $(R;+,-,*,0,1)$ which is isomorphic to the ring of polynomials in one variable of a non-trivial commutative ring with unity. Is the class of polynomial rings a first-order axiomatizable class? If so, what are the necessary axioms to axiomatize it? Also, bonus question, if that class is not axiomatizable, is the first-order theory associated with that class a finitely axiomatizable theory?

Comment: That's a good question, but you haven't done much to show us what work you have done on it (which may result in down-votes and closure). I would be surprised if these theories were axiomatisable, but would have to delve into papers that I haven't looked at for a long time to say more.

Comment: Seems unlikely that an ultrapower of a polynomial ring would still be a polynomial ring.

Comment: @EricWofsey: good point! If $R$ is finite then $R[x]$ will be countable, but an ultrapower of $R[x]$ must be uncountable.